# Using LRT with alpha = .2 in lmm reduction guided by PCA

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, dimensionality-reduction, likelihood-ratio

I'm wondering if it's valid to combine the methods for lmm reduction that [Bates et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04967) and [Matuschek et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01864) recommend:

Bates et al. suggest an iterative reduction of degenerate
maximal models. First they use PCA to obtain the appropriate dimensionality
of the variance-covariance matrix of the random-effect structure. Given
this reference point, they suggest to drop all non-significant variance
components and correlation parameters from the model. A significant loss in goodness of fit is indicated by significant LR differences - in
which case the parameter should stay in the model.

Is it, in this PCA context, a good idea to choose an alpha level of 0.2 as
model-selection criterion as suggested by Matuschek et al. to balance Type I error rate and power?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that this procedure is in fact the one they use in the [RePsychLing vignettes](https://github.com/dmbates/RePsychLing/tree/master/vignettes).